# Touchscreen Keyboard for the Mentally/Physically Challenged

Tags: linux, keyboard, xorg, touchscreen, software-recommendation

Hi this is my first time posting but i wanted to ask a question. First of all i'll outline my situation. Im currently working on a project to make a portable computer system for people who are mentally/physically disable (If needed I will post a pic of the plans for it). My plan is that it will have a touchscreen keyboard in the middle, ports on the back for HDMI and Audio and dedicated buttons around the outside of the touchscreen for things like copying and pasting (Idea behind this is so that the keyboard can be as simple and as uncluttered as possible to make it easier to navigate, so these are to eliminate the operator keys as the people using this will be parents and challenged people).

My problem is the touchscreen keyboard, while getting a touchscreen is easy the actual keyboard side of it isn't. I've looked all over the internet and can't find anything useful on it so I thought that I'd ask myself. The problem arises in several different place. While I could launch a Xorg session running something like [florence](http://florence.sourceforge.net/english.html) (Onscreen keyboard program) I still cant find anything useful on diverting the key presses from that application into a seperate one, and the program also isn't ideal for what im trying to do. Another possible way of doing it is to use VNC but I can't think of anyway to run only the Onscreen keyboard app when, unless i can find a way address the problem before this one, I'd have to VNC into the Xorg Session running the specialized app, (on a seperate screen just to clarify), which would cause the external screen to display the onscreen keyboard which is what im trying to avoid.

If anybody has any way to solve this problem I would be grateful as I have already put alot of work into designing the thing and don't want to have to abandon it. (PM me if you need more info). Thanks

Comment: Isn't using a touchscreen keyboard *more* physically challenging than a normal one?   It might be better to just disable the keys you want to disable...or look into keyboards that are actually built for this kind of purpose (simplified, large keys, color coded, etc).

Comment: The idea behind the touchscreen is to reduce the strength needed to push down on the keys (for people with movement related disabilities). It also allow for a simplified desktop and possible integration of a mousepad. It would also allow me, if I can figure out how to do it, to allow custom controls for each application on the device. Hope this helps.

Comment: Fair enough -- I am not an expert but have occasionally spent time around keyboard equipped physically disabled people, and this seems to be going in the opposite direction of what is actually used in the industry.   So if *"the idea behind the touchscreen"* means this is something you've discovered through research as successfully deployed already, ignore me...but if it is just one you've come up with yourself because you think it would be groundbreaking, I strongly suggest you think hard and do a sanity check in that regard.  Either way, good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PiTFT virtual keyboard link](https://blog.adafruit.com/2014/07/04/virtual-keyboard-for-the-raspberry-pi-raspberry_pi-piday-raspberrypi/). Actually it is not easy thing to do, you would have to somehow relay key presses to the system (or X server). But fortunately there are wiser people then us (or simply having more free time :P ). They guy above shows you how to setup virtual keyboard for PiTFT, i don't know if it works with arbitrary touch screen, but I have no means to check it.

Comment: Please mark as answering post if it will work :)